# How to write GQL `CONTAINS` comparator query in objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, gql

I use google cloud datastore to store and objectify to read the data. The entity that i use holds a list property and i would like to filter the records through multiple values and the results should be returned only if all the values are present in the list

GQL now supports CONTAINS query filter [link here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference?_ga=2.156134011.-1382412535.1550846607&_gac=1.45410320.1552897248.EAIaIQobChMI_rnc9aCL4QIVlw4rCh2eHQq2EAAYASAAEgKp6_D_BwE#operators_and_comparisons) . I would like to know how this can be achieved in objectify

Assuming there are three entities that holds a list field

```
(Entity1) => list = ["id1","id2","id3","id4"] 
(Entity2) => list = ["id1","id2","id3"]
(Entity3) => list = ["id1"]
queryList = ["id1","id2"]
```

How do i write an objectify query that uses contains. For example,  `ofy().load().type( Entity.class ).filter( "list contains" , queryList ).list();` so that only entities 1 and 2 are returned

I am familiar that `IN` filter `ofy().load().type( Entity.class ).filter( "list in" , queryList ).list();`
 will return all three entities.
But the requirement is to fetch only entities that has both `id1` and `id2`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an AND query, which should be `...filter("list", "id1").filter("list", "id2")`